# Checker Framework Eclipse Plugin Throws Exception when Loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, loading, checker-framework

I have Eclipse 4.6.2 and the plugin "Checker Framework Feature" 2.1.7 installed.

When the plug-in is first used (e.g. when I right-click and hover over the context-menu item "Checker Framework/Run Built-in Checker") the following error appears in the eclipse error log:

```
Plug-in checker.framework.eclipse.plugin was unable to load class org.checkerframework.eclipse.actions.CheckerActions$signednessAction.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/checkerframework/eclipse/actions/CheckerActions$signednessAction (wrong name: org/checkerframework/eclipse/actions/CheckerActions$SignednessAction)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
...
```

It seems like there is trouble with the uppercase / lowercase of class SignednessAction...

Can anyone help? I would love to use the Checker Framework!

Thanks so much!

Comment: There is also a second error message:

`The proxied handler for 'org.checkerframework.eclipse.actions.CheckerActions$signednessAction' could not be loaded. org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in checker.framework.eclipse.plugin was unable to load class org.checkerframework.eclipse.actions.CheckerActions$signednessAction. at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194) at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:178)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis about the mismatch in capitalization is correct.  Commit [fa8ee98](https://github.com/typetools/checker-framework/commit/fa8ee981801b3098eb97518ec57ddb3a829d6f74) fixes the bug.  You can re-build the Checker Framework Eclipse Plugin from the version control repository.  Alternately, the Checker Framework developers are often willing to make you a private release that fixes the bug so you don't have to wait until the next release.  You could email them at checker-framework-dev@googlegroups.com.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's great! They're releasing quite regularly. I think I'll wait